# Google sheets: Email each sheet to different email address listed in Cell G3

Tags: google-apps-script, scripting, google-sheets

I am building a sheet that emails individuals PDF reports.  I have this script working with a "hard coded" email address, however since each page of my google sheet needs to go to a different person. I am trying to figure out the language to make it look into the cell G3 of EACH SHEET and send the file to the respective email address.

IE sheet 1 emailed to address in G3 (dave@me.com)
Sheet 2 emailed to address in G3 (john@happy.com)

Thanks for your wisdom in advance.   Here is what i have so far that WORKS, but it sends the individual files to me (arademacher@XXXX.com), then i must fwd to each person.

```
function ZIP_PDF_EMAIL_INDIVIDUAL() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

// Email subject and message body

var url = ss.getUrl();
url = url.replace(/edit$/,'');

var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' // export as pdf
            + '&size=letter'                       // paper size
            + '&portrait=true'                    // orientation, false for landscape
            + '&fitw=true'                         // fit to width, false for actual size
            + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
            + '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' // hide pagenumbers and gridlines
            + '&fzr=false'                         // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
            + '&gid=';                             // the sheet's Id

var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
var sheets = ss.getSheets();



for (var i=0; i<sheets.length; i++) {

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + sheets[i].getSheetId(), {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
  }
});


var email = "arademacher@XXXX.com"
var message = "Monthly Report for " + ss.getName();
var subject = "PTO & Stipend Report - " + (new Date()).toString();

MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message, {attachments:[response]});

};
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var email = sheets[i].getRange("G3").getValue();
```

Comment: I feel like an idiot seeing this string, it was late :-) and I am still fairly new to this.  Thanks for your help, worked beautifully!